# Django: Queryset replacement for group by aggregate?

Tags: sql, database, django, sqlite, django-queryset

My table structure:

```
id | file_id(foreign key) | version_id(foreign key) | function_id(foreign key)
```

The id and (file_id, version_id, function_id) are unique.

I'm looking for Django querysets that can emulate the following sql query:

```
select *, max(version_id) from change_metrics group by function_id order by version_id
```

Basically I need to get the **latest version** for all unique file-function combinations, as there can exist many versions of a specific file-function combination. I'm currently using raw sql queries and I want to replace them with querysets.

I cannot change the database structure, but I'm open to all sorts of sql queries or ways of solving this problem

Comment: Please post the models you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your models look like the following:

```
class Function(models.Model):
    pass

class File(models.Model):
    pass

class Version(models.Model):
    pass

class ChangeMetric(models.Model):
    function = models.ForeignKey(Function)
    file = models.ForeignKey(File)
    version = models.ForeignKey(Version)
```

You should be able to do the following:

```
from django.db.models import Max
Function.objects.all().annotate(max_version=Max('changemetric_set__version___id'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

from django.db.models import Max
 q = change_metrics.objects.annotate(Max('version_id')).order_by('version_id')